# Where to solicit graduate student applicants for a unique teaching opportunity?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, recruiting

I am currently writing a grant proposal that involves a unique (and, I hope, very appealing) two-week teaching opportunity in the US for mathematics graduate students or recent Ph.D.'s.

I want to recruit applications via a competitive process, rather than only recruiting people whom I personally know. I intend to announce this opportunity at conferences, on social media, by sending e-mails to prospective teachers as well as senior faculty members (whom I would ask to pass the announcement on to anyone appropriate).

Are there any more formal venues in which it would also be appropriate to advertise? As a graduate student I mostly learned of opportunities by e-mails or by word of mouth, but I would like to advertise as widely as is practical.

Comment: May be advertising it at some groups in Social Media (FaceBook etc) could be good.

Comment: Put it through your university. Both of mine advertise(d) scholarships, summer programmes and research opps to graduates or near-graduates frequently on the university websites, and via email updates to the students in relevant departments. Anybody visiting the webpage can't help but see of, and anybody Googling for that kind of thing will have results showing the descriptive article and application pages.

Comment: @Nij: I'll have no problem reaching students at my own university. It's qualified students in my discipline at other universities I'm thinking of. Thanks though.

Comment: @Anonymous I was thinking more that they might be searching already, and having an "official" online object to find may help, in addition to anything else others will suggest.